# Missing Dependencies for Python

Tags: python, installation

I have some python code that I'd like to try to use in my Mathematica notebook. I have tried following the setup guide but I have run into some trouble (Mac). The Mathematica setup documentation says to:

1. Install the Python package manager (Python is already installed on Mac systems).
2. Install the "pyzmq" package for Python

I have tried this and it seems like it has successfully installed:

```
pip3 install --user pyzmq
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (22.0.3)
```

3. Verify the installation

```
FindExternalEvaluators["Python"]
```

[image]

I also tried this:

```
python3 -m pip install pyzmq
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (22.0.3)
```

Perhaps it put the packages in the wrong place? Why does Mathematica say missing dependencies but pyzmq requirement is already satisfied? Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any help *with what*? You didn't quite say what your specific problem is.

Comment: If what you are having problems with is to get a particular Python version loaded and Mathematica is not able to find it, try something along the lines of StartExternalSession[{"Python", "Executable" -> AbsoluteFileName["path/python3.8.2"]}]

Comment: Is it installed in the right place? Mathematica seems to be looking in `/usr/bin/` but the earlier message says it was installed under `./Library/` (whatever `.` was at the time)